# Change the height of div getting height for another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

sorry for the complex expression of my question.
I would set the height of the div #space, taking the height of another div that's have a class .ls-wp-fullwidth-container.
I try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var altezza = document.getElementById(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").clientHeight;
$("#space").height(altezza);
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
var altezza = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height();
$("#space").height(altezza);
});
```

How can I do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why don't you proceed the same way in document.ready and resize ? the way you do it in your resize event seems good

Comment: You should use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HzQhL/

```
$("#space").height($(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the div through class selector by `$(.className)` but you used  `document.getElementById(".ls-wp....")` which is wrong

**Updated**

*should be*

```
var altezza = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height();
```

Or

```
var altezza = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container")[0].clientHeight;
```

*instead of*

```
document.getElementById(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").clientHeight;
```

When you use the `class` selector to fetch the data it returns array of matched elements. And when you use `id` it returns matched element only.

Comment: Or `document.querySelector(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").clientHeight;`

Comment: try this `$(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height()`, please have a look udpated code.

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
var height = $(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").css("height");
$("#space").css("height", height);
```